# Advice about struggles with new role

Tags: career-development, career-switch, anxiety, knowledge-transfer, impostor-syndrome

I had turned down this role last year, and stepped down from a management role.  I took the time to get better in my old role and become more confident.  The opportunity came around again, so this time I jumped on it. (Internal transfer)

The new position is more visible and will give me more opportunities in the future.  However, I feel like I may be in over my head. I was encouraged by both my new manager and old to take the promotion.  I am a bit overwhelmed in my new role, as it very different than my previous one.

What are some strategies that I may take to set myself up for success in this new role, and what steps may I take to avoid self-sabotage and giving into "Imposter syndrome"

Comment: You're getting downvotes because this is not a specific, actionable issue. It's much more broad. The best advice we can give is something like "Read books that pertain to your new role" or similar generic answers.

Comment: @RobinClower My edit fixed that.  The user is new, and we can give far better advice then that.

Answer (score 3):

Part of "imposter syndrome" is the simple fact that we tend to create smaller versions in our minds of ourselves as a method of staying safe.  If you are completely competent in your position, you will get plenty of praise, but not working to your potential.

The real imposter was you in your old role.  Your old manager sees your potential, your new manager sees your potential.  It is time that you do as well.

**STRATEGIES:**

- celebrate every victory, no matter how small.  Start with getting the promotion.
- "There is no failure, only success training" -Kevin Smith.  (memorize that quote)
- Mistakes are inevitable, they are also how you learn
- Focus on the solutions, not the problems.
- project confidence.
- Ask for help after you exhaust other options, and tell them so.  "Boss, I tried X,Y, and Z.  I'm stuck.
- DOCUMENT your achievements. This serves two purposes:  You can remind yourself of them and be proud and you can also list them at your annual review
- Try to recognize the talent that others see in you

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I know this wasn’t the typical  question/ feedback request as I am new here.    I’m going to take this tidbit to heart!      “. If you are completely competent in your position, you will get plenty of praise, but not working to your potential.”

Comment: @ADuggan Thank you, and welcome to the workplace.  Just as an FYI, try to make your questions, and ask for strategies instead of advice, and they will be better recieved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your humility is exceptional and a great asset lacking in many people who take on managerial roles.

Having said that, do not let it turn into self-doubt or fence-sitting. Your reports need clear and confident guidance. More importantly for yourself, try to make your most important report the person staring at you in the mirror.

How do we best manage our reports? By setting clear expectations and communicating effectively. If you are feeling overwhelmed, write down why. Prepare a plan to manage your time and responsibilities better. Check in with yourself in 1-2 weeks. Are you making progress against this plan?

If self-adjustment isn't working, it's time to wonder if your workload is appropriate. Discuss this with your manager. Leaders less introspective than you may need to be told by *their* reports that the current org chart isn't working for them.

And finally, try to find any internal documents describing your current job description. How are you measuring up? What's missing? My guess is that it doesn't paint the full picture, and a discussion on exactly how is a wonderful place to start a conversation with *your* manager. If it is accurate and you simply *are* overwhelmed, try to create a plan to ease yourself into it. Rome wasn't built in a day; it's extremely typical for people to be doing this job long before an official promotion is acquired.